# RxJS 6 get a filtered list of array of Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

In my ThreadService class, I have a function `getThreads()` that return me a `Observable<Thread[]>` with all my threads.

Now, I would like to have another version of my function with my threads filtered by a selected theme : function `getSelectedThemeThreads(theme: Theme)`.

I tried with the operators `map` and `filter` but I have the following error message `Property 'theme' does not exist on type 'Thread[]`.

Below the code I am working on :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Thread } from '../models/thread.model';
import { Theme } from '../models/theme.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ThreadService {
  private threadsUrl = 'api/threads';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getThreads(): Observable<Thread[]> {
  return this.http.get<Thread[]>(this.threadsUrl);
}

getSelectedThemeThreads(): Observable<Thread[]> {
  return this.http.get<Thread[]>(this.threadsUrl).pipe(
    map(threads => threads),
    filter(thread => thread.theme.id === theme.id)
  );
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I think threads is an array you should do like map(threads => threads.filter) filter in this case is standard js

Comment: filter can be a starndar js (then use inside map) or Rxjs https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/filter.html. But..What is theme.id in thread.theme.id=== **theme.id** ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I made an example of this [StackBlitz / angular6-filter-result](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-filter-result?file=src%2Fapp%2Fflower.service.ts)

The main idea is to filter in the `map()` as the filter will get an array of objects.

```
getSelectedThemeThreads(theme: string): Observable<Flower[]> {
    return this.http.get<Flower[]>(this.threadsUrl).pipe(
      map(result =>
        result.filter(one => one.theme === theme)
      )
    )
  }
```

Comment: side note: this answer relies on javascript's native array filter method, not filter in rxjs.

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there. Using this `map(threads => threads)` does nothing but you probably wanted to use this instead:

```
mergeMap(threads => threads) // will turn Observable<Thread[]> into Observable<Thread>
```

`concatMap` or `switchMap` will work as well. The `mergeMap` operator will iterate the array and emit each item separately so then you can use `filter()` as you're doing already.

You could of course use also this:

```
map(threads => threads.find(thread => thread.theme.id === theme.id)),
filter(thread => thread !== undefined),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by using the following code.

```
getSelectedThemeThreads(theme): Observable<Thread[]> {
    return this.http.get<Thread[]>(this.threadsUrl)
    .map(res => res)
    .filter(thread => thread.theme.id == theme.id);
}
```

Comment: the trick about this is that thread at "filter(thread" is Thread[ ] not Thread :| looks like this won't work

Answer (score 0):

Just change `map(threads => threads)` to `mergeAll()`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `grupoby` [operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/groupby.html):

```
getSelectedThemeThreads(): Observable<Thread[]> {
  return this.http.get<Thread[]>(this.threadsUrl).pipe(
    groupby(thread => thread.id),
    mergeAll(group$ => group$.pipe(
      reduce((acc, cur) =>[...acc, cur], [])
    )
  );
}
```

Let me know how this code works for you. In any case, [if you need to play with it, a while ago a came with this exampl](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-groupby)e, I hope it helps you to clarify.