# JavaScript rxjs filter not working when returning an Observable

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I am using Angular 9.  I am trying to filter values in an Observable, however it is not having an affect. I think the way I handle the Observable is wrong.

Below, the `_filter` function is supposed to filter the `this.filteredApproverOptions`, however I find that no filter is applied and the entire list is always populated.

```js
private setFilteredApproverOptions(): void {
    for (const field in this.approvalEditFormGroup.controls) {
        this.approvalEditFormGroup.get(field).valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
        if (value && typeof value.valueOf() === "string") {
            this.filteredApproverOptions = this._filter(value);
          const x = parseInt(field.charAt(9));
          const y = parseInt(field.charAt(12));
            this.filteredApproverOptions = this.filteredApproverOptions.pipe(map(    // obs.pipe(map(...)) is changing each value coming in an observable/subject
                    pArr => pArr.map(p => ({...p, x: x, y: y}))          // arr.map(...) is changing each value in an array
          ));
        }
      });
    }
}

private _filter(value: string): Observable<Person[]> {

    const filterValue: string = value.toLowerCase();
    let respApprovalState: Observable<Person[]> = this.getApproverOptions(filterValue);
    respApprovalState.subscribe(approverOptions => {
    return approverOptions.filter((option: Person) => {

        let filter: boolean =
        (option.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue) || option.lastName.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue))

        return filter;  // if this returns true or false, there is no difference
    });
    });
    return respApprovalState;
}
```

**Question**

How can I apply the filter to `this.filteredApproverOptions`?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running side-effect inside subscribe, you need to return new observable and use it in the future. Same way as you are doing `map` above, for example:

```
return respApprovalState.pipe(
  filter(option => ...)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will give it a try.

Comment: If I do a `return respApprovalState.pipe(...` it wants to return a `Observable<Person>` and not a `Observable<Person[]>`. I need a list.

Comment: Not enough details to answer this, you might need create **minimal** reproducible example on stackblitz.com then I will be able to suggest

Comment: Thanks for your help, I used the answer from here, and got it working:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50659367/rxjs-6-get-a-filtered-list-of-array-of-observable

Comment: `    return respApprovalState.pipe(
      map((result: Person[]) => result.filter(p => false)
      )
    );`

Answer (score 1):

To use correctly an Observable you should not subscribe to it until you consume the data (at the end).

You must pipe your Observable and add your filter in it:

```js
return respApprovalState.pipe(
  filter(data => ...) // Filter the data running through your pipe
);
```

Unfortunately, you do not provide enough information to know what is `approverOptions`, we will not be able to provide you a working example.

But you should be able to do it yourself after understanding the pattern of Rxjs Observables.

Here is more information about the filter operator: https://rxmarbles.com/#filter